# In a system of two charges, if one charge suddenly disappears, does the force on other charge vanish instantaneously?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, relativity, gravitational-waves, causality

It is commonly asked that if the Sun disappears, will Earth shoot off in a tangent instantaneously or after some time? We know from the theory of relativity that the gravitational waves travel at the speed of light. And the Earth will shoot off in a tangent in about 8 mins.

Is this also true for electrostatic forces? Is there anything like the electrostatic force waves? an electrostatic counterpart of gravity.

And what about other forces i.e. the weak and strong nuclear forces?

Comment: There are no instantaneous interactions . All information transfer is bounded by the velocity of light c.

Comment: I'm closing this post as off-topic as a charge cannot suddenly disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there anything like electrostatic force waves?"

Yes, also known as electromagnetic waves or light.

The electromagnetic force, of which electrostatic force is a subset, is carried by none other than photons, which travel at the speed of light.

The strong force is carried by gluons, which are massless and therefore also travel at the speed of light, so disturbances in the strong force should too.

The weak force, on the other hand is carried by massive W and Z bosons, so it would travel slower than light speed.